# Azure AD B2B Invite API: disable verification

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Our application is mainly used by internal users, who authenticate through AAD. Some pages need to be accessible to third-parties. Right now we are using custom tokens, but would like to switch to Azure AD B2B Invite API.

We just did some manual test runs and it seems to work exactly as expected, except for one thing: when inviting my standalone email address, I was asked to create a Microsoft account, which is fine. However, to do so, I had to first verify my email address (code sent to email) and then my phone (code sent via sms).

Is there any way to disable ideally both or at least the phone verification?
The only resource I found so far states that it's possible in B2C, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standalone email addresses has to undergo the [invitation redemption process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-redemption-experience). In order to be able to invite people without redemption in Azure AD B2B you need an account with directory read permission of the partners tenant. Then you can add that user to your tenant with "Guest Inviter" role. Then that user can add the users to your tenant without invitation redemption process. Refer: [Azure AD B2B: How to bulk add guest users without invitation redemption.](https://justidm.wordpress.com/2017/05/07/azure-ad-b2b-how-to-bulk-add-guest-users-without-invitation-redemption/)